# WPF: Could not load file or assembly error in the designer but application runs with no problems

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2022

To try to solve another issue with the designer I've deleted bin and obj directories. Since then I'm facing this error while being in the designer:
"The error message "Could not load file or assembly 'DesktopClient, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the specified file.". **I can run the app with no problems the error is only related to the designer**.
The DesktopClient assembly is the assembly of the WPF project.

I've already tried:

- Restarting the IDE
- Updating the IDE

The project targets .NET 8.0.

Here is XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DesktopClient.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:root="clr-namespace:DesktopClient"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DesktopClient.Views"
        xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:DesktopClient.ViewModels"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:DesktopClient.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModels:MainWindowViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=true}">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="IModeViewModel">
            <StackPanel>                
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:OrdersListModeViewModel}">
            <!-- some content -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- some content -->
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Are you using any types defined in `DesktopClient.dll` in your XAML directly or indirectly? Perhaps  as a Design-Time `DataContext=`` object - or dependency properties?

Comment: @Dai Yes, I'm using the types. I've updated my question with XAML code.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your .vs folder in that project? That should clear out any bad intellisence state.

Comment: I will write it as an answer so that it might help others. Go ahead and accept it/upvote if it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes intellisense gets into a bad state, and deleting the `.vs` folder will clear that out. It's not a super elegant solution, but it should work.

[image: delete the .vs folder]